# Custom gradle plugin on TeamCity different behavior then local

Tags: regex, groovy, teamcity, gradle-plugin

I'm facing a thing that is confusing me. I have this groovy code:

```
def static extractTaskIdsFromLine(String orderName, String line) {
        print("comment line = \"" + line + "\"")
        def pattern = ~/${orderName}-[0-9]+/
        return line != null ? line.findAll(pattern) : new ArrayList<>()
    }
```

On my local machine everything looks fine and all tests pass. But with the same conditions this code on Team City with the same input gives no one matches. Both encodings and input parameters are the same. 
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What does the orderName hold? Try adding `\Q` and `\E`: `def pattern = ~/\Q${orderName}\E-[0-9]+/` if there are any special characters.

Comment: there is no any special character for orderName var. I have tested this function by auto tests, everythigs work well for same strings on my local machine, but does not work on any build agent on TeamCity. Mb there is any difference then it is execeuting on TC?